# Dynamically add Items to Combobox VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have 2 combobox in windows application. I want to programmatically add Items to second combobox based on what is selected in the first combobox.

This is what I do in the selected index change of the combobox:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Try
        If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
            ComboBox2.Items.Add("MM")
            ComboBox2.Items.Add("PP")
        ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
            ComboBox2.Items.Add("SMS")
        ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
            ComboBox2.Items.Add("MMS")
            ComboBox2.Items.Add("SSSS")
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

It works fine, however, if I keep selecting different items it's keep adding the value over and over. I would like to add those values only once.

Also, when I add an item I would prefer to add an ID with the item description. I tried:

```
ComboBox2.Items.Add("SSSS", "1")
```

It seems that it's not working.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Clear the ComboBox before adding by using **ComboBox2.Items.Clear()**

Comment: define "not working" does it have to do with the "too many arguments" error for `.Add`?  If you want to store more than one piece of info you will have to store it in a class.  [Example using files](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24397531/1070452) but the class can define anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Try
        If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
            If Not (ComboBox2.Items.Contains("MM")) And Not (ComboBox2.Items.Contains("PP")) Then
                ComboBox2.Items.Add("MM")
                ComboBox2.Items.Add("PP")
            End If
        ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
            If Not (ComboBox2.Items.Contains("SMS")) Then
                ComboBox2.Items.Add("SMS")
            End If
        ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
            If Not (ComboBox2.Items.Contains("MMS")) And Not (ComboBox2.Items.Contains("SSSS")) Then
                ComboBox2.Items.Add("MMS")
                ComboBox2.Items.Add("SSSS")
            End If
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding:

> "Also, when I add an item I would prefer to add an ID with the item
>   description"

You can use the `AddRange` function of the ComboBox or make a list as I show here and use it as a datasource - as @Plutonix mentioned in his comment.

With it you can add an array of objects of a type that holds a value and a description, given that you override the `ToString` base function (of `Object` class).

Here is such a class:

```
Public Class CodeAndDescription
    Public code As String
    Public description As String

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Me.code + " - " + description
    End Function
End Class
```

Now make a list of that upper class and add it to the combobox. Something like:

```
Dim lstItems As List(Of CodeAndDescription) = GetList()
yourComboBox.Items.Clear()
yourComboBox.Items.AddRange(lstItems.ToArray)
```

Don't forget to Cast the retrieved object when you take it out of the combo:

```
Dim codeDesc As CodeAndDescription = TryCast(yourComboBox.Items(0), CodeAndDescription)
```

I've done this on a check list, but I think the principle is the same for a ComboBox.

Comment: you dont even need AddRange and make a copy of the items in the process.  just use the List(T) as a datasource

Comment: Oh? In what case would adding a Type to the CBO work where List(T) as a datasource not work?